# asm.js 10* slower in firefox 48 than firefox 45

Tags: firefox, emscripten, asm.js

I'm developing a math web application (http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7eparisse/xcasen.html) compiled from C++ to javascript by emscripten 1.34.1. Performance are good inside Firefox 45, for example factoring 2^128+1 to 59649589127497217×5704689200685129054721 by ifactor(2^128+1) takes 0.1s==time(ifactor(2^128+1)) on my Mac with Firefox 45. But inside Firefox 48 (and also Firefox nightly), it is much slower, 10* to 20* slower for the first run, next runs are 2* to 10* slower) :
[link to test](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7eparisse/xcasen.html#+ifactor(2^128+1)&+time(ifactor(2^128+1)&)

Is it related to the emscripten version? Is there a workaround (other than telling my user to downgrade their Firefox install and stop upgrade)?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your application uses asm.js memory growth (the ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH emcc option). Browsers have [decided to stop supporting that](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/09E_WEk193E), which means asm.js+memory growth no longer gets asm.js optimizations.

If you can avoid using memory growth, then the app should run at full asm.js speed as it used to.

Comment: Indeed, replacing -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 by -s TOTAL_MEMORY=64000000 seems to fix the problem, thanks!